# For Loop on Plotly Python

Tags: python, for-loop, plotly

I am trying to replace

```
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
```

with the for loop code

```
totalPlot = 2
x = ['trace%s'%(item + 1) for item in range(totalPlot)]
y = [(item + 1) for item in range(totalPlot)]
z = totalPlot * [1]

for i, j, k in zip(x, y, z):
    fig.append_trace(i, j, k)
```

so that it will be more scalable as I add more figures. However, the loop code keeps returning 'TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment'. What did I do wrong?

Here is the code similar with the one from [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/):

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[4, 5, 6]
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[20, 30, 40],
    y=[50, 60, 70],
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)


# ----- Loop here ------- START
fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, 2, 1)
# ----- Loop here ------- END

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=600, title='i <3 subplots')
py.iplot(fig, filename='make-subplots')
```

Comment: Exactly which line is giving you an error? The error `'TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment'` tends to arise when you try to modify a string object in place (change a character for example.) Strings are immutable, so you can't "change" one but you can make a changed copy.

Comment: @machine yearning: This line is giving me the TypeError: 'fig.append_trace(i, j, k)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code it looks like `trace1` is some kind of array-like data structure:

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[4, 5, 6]
)
```

So I imagine that when you call `fig.append_trace(trace1, 1, 1)` it's adding an element to this array-like structure, the first parameter.

However in your reimplementation, you've turned the trace data into a string:

```
x = ['trace%s'%(item + 1) for item in range(totalPlot)]
...
for i, j, k in zip(x, y, z):
    fig.append_trace(i, j, k)
```

Here `i` is an element of `x` which is in turn a string like `'trace%s'%(item + 1)`. But you cannot append an element to a string. Python strings are immutable. So when you call `append_trace` you naturally get an error here about not being able to do what you want with strings.

Comment: I see. I will fix the x and make it an array. Thank you for the explanation. :)

Comment: Or rather, `x` is already an array. What you probably need to do is make sure each element of `x` is a `go.Scatter` object, instead of a string.